# Oracle connect three tables in SQL query

Tags: php, sql, database, oracle, join

I am using oracle database and php.I have 3 tables:

```
| users  |         | user/group |          | groups  |
----------         --------------          -----------
| u_id   |         | gr_id      |          | gr_id   |
| u_name |         | u_id       |          | gr_name |
|u_status|         |            |          |         |
```

I need to get all names of the users who is in a group that has certain gr_name AND who has status...say 'OK';
I have tried using JOIN like so:

```
SELECT u_name FROM users 
    JOIN user/group ON user.u_id = user/group.u_id
    JOIN groups ON user/group.gr_id = groups.gr_id
WHERE u_status = 'OK'
```

The query return all users who is in groups.. How and where can I insert something like:

```
WHERE gr_name = 'blah-blah'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

`WHERE u_status = 'OK' AND gr_name = 'blah-blah'`

Comment: Duhh.. Of course... Silly me...That was a stupid question.. Thanks iamsleepy!